# Toggle Show/Hide `active` class on li's in react js

Tags: reactjs

Hi i want to show/hide the class when click on li's in a ul. Following is the code of ul:

```
<ul className="period">
                            <li className="" onClick={this.onChangeForDays} value="Indefinitely">Indefinitely</li>
                            <li className="active" onClick={this.onChangeForDays} value="1">1 Day</li>
                            <li className="" onClick={this.onChangeForDays} value="7">1 Week</li>
                            <li className="" onClick={this.onChangeForDays} value="30">1 Month</li>
                            <li className="" onClick={this.onChangeForDays} value="90">3 Months</li>
                            <li className="" onClick={this.onChangeForDays} value="180">6 Months</li>
                        </ul>
```

So what i want to achieve is to write a common function when i click on any of the `<li>` it should show `active` class for that particular `<li>` and hide the `active` class for all other `<li>`.
One more thing i want to show `active` class by default on one of the `<li>` as well so lets say i want first `<li>` to have `active` class by default, i tried to write the function but i got stuck.

```
   onChangeForDays(changeEvent) {
    this.setState({
        'fordays': changeEvent.target.value,
        'isActive': true
    });
}
```

how can i achieve this can someone help.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Hassan, please try my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for the answer it works fine

Comment: You're welcome! Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the list of items in an array, and give each item object a `clicked` property like this.

```
let listItems = [
  { days: "Indefinitely", clicked: true, desc: "Indefinitely" },
  { days: 1, clicked: false, desc: "1 Day" },
  { days: 7, clicked: false, desc: "1 Week" },
  { days: 30, clicked: false, desc: "1 Month" },
  { days: 90, clicked: false, desc: "3 Months" },
  { days: 180, clicked: false, desc: "6 Months" }
];
```

This pattern will make your code more manageable. Also, it will make it easier to keep track of the "active" state of each item. Then create a list-iterating function to render the list-items with their corresponding days.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-ptolemy-oguo1

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

let listItems = [
  { days: 1, clicked: true, desc: "1 Day" },
  { days: 7, clicked: false, desc: "1 Week" },
  { days: 30, clicked: false, desc: "1 Month" },
  { days: 90, clicked: false, desc: "3 Months" },
  { days: 180, clicked: false, desc: "6 Months" }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listItems: listItems
    };
  }

  handleOnClick = e => {
    const { listItems } = this.state;

    const updatedItems = listItems.map(item => {
      if (item.days == e.target.value) {
        return {
          ...item,
          clicked: true
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...item,
          clicked: false
        };
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      listItems: updatedItems
    });
  };

  createListItems = () => {
    const { listItems } = this.state;

    return listItems.map(item => {
      return (
        <li
          onClick={this.handleOnClick}
          className={item.clicked ? "active" : ""}
          value={item.days}
        >
          {item.desc}
        </li>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.createListItems()}</ul>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The `handleOnClick` function will create an updated array of items. It will find the item selected and set `clicked` to true. All other items will have click set to `false`.

To determine what `class` each item will have, we use a ternary operator to check whether its own `clicked` property is `true`, which again can be changed by `handleOnClick()`

```
<li
  onClick={this.handleOnClick}
  className={item.clicked ? "active" : ""}
  value={item.days}
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.state.fordays` in `render` to check which element is active

```
<li className={this.state.fordays === 'Indefinitely' ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.onChangeForDays} value="Indefinitely">Indefinitely</li>
```